# Deploying django project on apache

Tags: django, apache

My django project `mysite` is located at path: `/web/mysite`

My virtualenv `testEnv` is located at path: `/web/testEnv`

All files and directories in in the above mentioned two paths are owned by `www-data : www-data`

All directories have permission `drwxr-xr-x`, files have permission `-rw-r--r--` and `db.sqlite3` has permission `-rw-rw-r--`.

I have added the following configuratiom in the `apache` `default` configuration file.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /web/mysite
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /web/mysite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ... Some more config here ...

    Alias /static /web/mysite/mysite/static
    <Directory /web/mysite/mysite/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /web/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/web/testEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /web/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart the `apache` server I get the following error,

```
ImportError: No module named mysite.settings
```

I have checked multiple tutorials with still no luck and would need some guidance on the same.

**[EDIT]** Have added `wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: What does your wsgi.py look like?

Comment: You need to add the Python paths to use to `sys.path`, I'll post a wsgi.py as an answer soon. Are your wsgi.py and settings.py in the same directory, and are they in /web/mysite/mysite/settings.py or /web/mysite/settings.py?

Comment: Yes they in the same directory. They are in `/web/mysite/mysite/settings.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the path to the virtualenv in python-path, but you also need to add the path to your project. Change the line to

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/web/testEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/web/mysite
```